# Will the foreground activity get paused automatically

Tags: android

suppose that an activity is in foreground and it is in idle state for some instance. Will that activity goes to paused state automatically???

suppose that I have opened an activity and went out on some other work.will that activity enter into pause state by itself after some time automatically?

Comment: If the Android device goes to sleep it will pause the activity. If the device stays awake so does the activity.

Answer (score 1):

An `Activity` gets paused in the following cases:

- Activity goes background (user presses Home button)
- Another activity goes foreground (e.g. user launches another app)
- User locks the phone (lock screen becomes the new foreground activity)
- User rotates the phone (device configuration gets changed)
- Activity finishes itself or sends itself to background

Otherwise than that, your activity should not be paused "automatically".

Answer (score 0):

Hav a look at the lifecycle image, especially the parts bwlo `Activity Running`

[image]